# Set backgroundColor on half of the highchart area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/4rTBY/

```
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    backgroundColor: {
        linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0,  x2: 0, y2: 0 },
        stops: [
            [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
            [0.5, 'rgb(200, 200, 255)']
        ]
    },
    type: 'line'
}
```

As we use `backgroundColor` whole background gets colored. I only want 50% of the background of the chart to get colored from the bottom.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appointed three points, all three in the middle of the screen (`x: 0.5`). The reason for three points is that the rest of the page continues to paint the nearest point's color and it will be gradient if you assign two. I put the first two points near each other so that the gradient effect wont show:

```
linearGradient: { x1: 0.5, y1: 0.5, x2: 0.5, y2: 0.51, x3: 0.5, y3: 1 },
stops: [[0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
        [1, 'rgb(200, 200, 255)'],
        [2, 'rgb(200, 200, 255)']]
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4rTBY/625/